# Get/Set cookie with WebBrowser class C#

Tags: c#, cookies

I need in some help about class "WebBrowser" in C#. How I can send a cookie with GetRequest and save a cookie from Response?
Why this code don't work and how to correct error?

```
private void GetMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.Cookie = "https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx?mkt=ru-RU&lic=1";
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx?mkt=ru-RU&lic=1");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method `InternetSetCookie` that can be called from `WebBrowserControl`, it should look something like this.

First you import the `InternetSetCookie` function:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string UrlName, string CookieName, string CookieData);
```

and then you call it from your click handler.

```
private void GetMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InternetSetCookie(url, "JSESSIONID", Globals.ThisDocument.sessionID); 
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url); 
}
```